# how to set value to input type="text" in laravel livewire inside "foreach"

Tags: input, laravel-livewire

I have this code in blade
I try to set value of item quantity to input type="text" which inside @foreach ..... @endforeach
for updating value each one alone.

```
@foreach ($Carts as $index => $Cart)
    <input type="text" wire:model="Quantity.{{ $index }}" value="{{ $Cart->items_qty }}"/>
@endforeach
```

Code in Component

```
public $BarcodeSearch, $Quantity;

public function render()
{
   return view('livewire.cashier',[
       'Carts' => Cart::all()
   ]);
}
```

---

How do I show the value in the fields? "Quantity"

[The picture is for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFR1P.png)

Answer (score 0):

To display the Quantity of your component you should use :
`{{ $cashier->Quantity }}`

You can't use it like this
`wire:model="Quantity.{{ $index }}"` because this is not how model works.

Model is based on `wire:model="PropertyToMonitor"` or `wire:model="ParentComponent.PropertyToMonitor"`. See documentation of model [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties#data-binding)

Comment: I try {{ $cashier->Quantity }} but not work with me. Can you give me an example?